# Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop Issue

Tags: login

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, and after a power failure, I cannot login.
The computer has been working fine for a few months before this suddenly happened.

**Symptoms are:**

- After an login attempt, screen blacks out for about 15 seconds, and returns to the login screen.
- I can log in as a guest without a problem
- I can log in as myself through tty1~tty6

**I tried/checked the following with no success:**

1. Changing `.Xauthority` ownership didn't work
   `chown username:username .Xauthority`
2. Changing the user directory rights didn't work
   `sudo chmod -R u+w /home/[username]`
3. I tried meddling with lightdm
   `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
4. `sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup`
   `sudo service lightdm restart`
5. There was nothing in `.xsession-errors`
6. Tried `gdm` instead of `lightdm`, but it had the exact same issue
7. Uninstalled `lightdm` and reinstalled
8. `/tmp` directory does show `drwxrwxrwt`

None of these solutions I found on-line worked. Can anyone please help?

**Edit 1):**
When I typed `sudo tail /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, there are 10 lines showing. (All starting with `DEBUG:`):

```
Activating VT 7  
Activating login1 session c3  
Session pid=8697: Greeter connected version=1.10.4  
Session pid=8697: Greeter start authentication for [username]  
Session pid=8769: Started with service 'lightdm', username [username]  
Session pid=8769: Got 1 message from PAM  
Session pid=8697: Propmpt greeter with 1 message  
User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User 1000 changed (repeated 3 times)
```

Also, when I type `ls /usr/share/xsessions/`, it shows

```
gnome.desktop    ubuntu.desktop
```

**Edit 2):**

`sudo grep 'lightdm:' /var/log/auth.log | tail` gives the following, all starting with `lightdm:`:

```
pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0  
pam_unix(lighdm:session): session closed for user [username]  
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so  
pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
pam_ck_connector(lightdm-greeter:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0  
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so  
pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user [username]"  
(this one starts with sudo: instead of lightdm:) [username] : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/[username] ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep lightdm: /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: Anything in the display manager log (e.g. `sudo tail /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`)? is your usual user session listed in the xsessions directory (`ls /usr/share/xsessions/`)?

Comment: Thanks - how about the auth.log? e.g. `sudo grep 'lightdm:' /var/log/auth.log | tail`

Comment: This is way beyond what I understand, but I'll tell you what I do see: Pam is some sort of security system for your computer. It is trying to do something with kwalletmanager, the program which is a password safe for KDE. But, it is trying to access what appears to be a library it uses to do so - /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so and can't find it. Check if that file exists and what its permissions are if it does (along with the directory it lives in). You might install apt-file and use it to find what package that file comes from to see if it is installed and updated correctly. apt-file update 1st

Comment: Apparently, pam_kwallet.so is something optional for Kubuntu ([https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1309535]).  Commenting out those optional lines removes the errors, but didn't solve the problem.  I also installed Xubuntu and Xfce to see if it would work, but didn't. :(

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (formatting the previous installation), and yet, I have the exact same issue.  I'm thinking the issue is somewhere in the [user] folder?  Can anybody save me, please!  This is my research computer, and my dissertation research will be set back until I get this running again! :(

Comment: I may have the same problem. I haven't fixed it yet, but did find out that other desktop environments do work: LXDE for example, or gnome-fallback. You can click the ubuntu logo next to your username in the login screen and select a different environment.

Comment: You can follow this [ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem][1]. Hope After that, Your problem will be solved.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem

Comment: I know this isn't the correct answer, but I don't have the reputation to be able to comment. From my experience I would suggest: Try the boot-repair-cd, from here http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ . You can download and make it a bootable USB from any pc following here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . Do you have any videocard? Or some special video configuration in your profile - multiple monitors. Also, as last resort, @orvi is correct, try following https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem, to get a new working session you can l

Answer (score 4):

For me, the solution was simply running this command from tty1:

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
```

Comment: +1, This is the most common cause (wrong permissions on `~/.Xauthority`).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but in case the problem persists, her's what I'd do.
This looks a lot like a "user" specific problem, especially after the reinstall.

First of all, try to create a new user (`sudo adduser "username"`) and see if that works. If it does, you have the confirmation that something in your local configuration is wrong.

Try to start with a new, fresh configuration with the following commands (after logging in with your problematic username from a tty)

```
mkdir ~/cfg-backups
mv ~/.config ~/cfg-backup
mv ~/.dconf ~/cfg-backup
```

And check if you're back in business. You can than restore any configs from the backups that you should require.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the following method solved the trouble

First login into tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.

Reinstall Ubuntu Desktop (i.e Unity)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Some other tips are available here : [ubuntu 14.04 login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem)