# Server 14.04 froze and now I have a login loop

Tags: 14.04, server, login

I have spent hours trying to get past this but to no avail.
The server froze. I had to reset it using the power button.
Now at the terminal login, I enter credentials, the standard screen showing server info flashes for a fraction of a second, and then I am back at the login screen. I have gone through many similar issues, including [Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588721/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-issue) but none have resolved my issue.

Specifically I have:

1.Renamed .Xauthority to .oldXauthority

2.Verified that the disk isn't full (only 51% used)

3. Created a new user and gave it full rights and tried to login (it also just looped)

4.Run chown -R sysadmin:sysadmin on the sysadmin folder

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use recovery mode? Press Shift on boot (eg at the computer vendor screen) until the GRUB menu shows. Select advanced options using the up/down and enter/return keys on your keyboard. Then go into the first entry you see that has `recovery mode` at the end of it. Press enter on it, then try fix from there (maybe look at logs?)

Comment: Those are the steps I had to take to try the steps above.

Comment: So I am booting into recovery mode. I first enable networking to mount in rw. Then I drop to root shell prompt. I have noticed that internet doesn't appear to work - apt-get always fails to resolve. Not sure if that is important or not. Looked through lots of different logs to search for clues but not finding anything yet.