# Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop

Tags: login

I'm a new Ubuntu user and am learning as I go.  The question I have is different from the other login loop problems posted here:

- [ubuntu 14.04 login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588721/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-issue)

When I visit the Odin Project website, I am logged out of my computer and then get stuck in a login loop.  It only happens when I visit that site (so far) and I have to restart my computer in order to be able to log in again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed if you click the third party software installed on the installation of ubuntu. Ubuntu will try to install Nvidia drivers. Nvidia drivers mess around with the GUI a bit. Thus causing it to not load. I recommend re-installing Ubuntu and install all of the drivers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I was able to login through tty terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+f6`) but when tried to login via Login Screen I always got stuck in a loop. I tried to find `.xsession-errors` and `.Xauthority` files but both files didn't exist in my computer. After some digging I found that my home directory was encrypted and my system can't unencrypt it.

I have recently changed my password using `sudo passwd username` but it resulted in the login loop problem. I simply changed my password back to the original one and now I am able to login to my system.