# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in login loop

Tags: loop-device

Seen many questions on this matter, but as I can not access CTRL-ALT-F1/2 I'm stuck into this loop. 
It keeps asking for password, clean orpheants and back to login. 
As I can NOT open any manager/control window it's somekind of strange behavior. 
I can NOT login as myself OR as guest. :-(

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/a/785263/518562