# nothing helps to solve login loop

Tags: system-installation, login

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 installed alongside windows 10 using **Something else** in installation process. Recently I have installed Cuda 8.0.44 and cuDNN v5.1 Library for Linux to learn Tensorflow with GPU support.
I was logging in without any failure, but today it got stuck. I wanted to install Sublimetext and followed the tutorial given in Youtube. I installed **synaptic package manager** and reload it as shown in the tutorial. But the Reload failed. I thought rebooting might help and restarted the device, since then I cant log in to my desktop.
I tried several ways to solve the issue such as:
[this from Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and 
[this from Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG4deLa_vK8)

In fact, there was a quick Nvidia window for, say, a millisecond when I switched it on. Now, it does not show up.

Additionally, my laptop functions strangely, it gets shut down with a strange crack noise since I dual-booted it with Ubuntu.

Question:

1.How can I log in to my Desktop again?

2. Is it something wrong with my computer functioning in this manner?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I can provide any further information if necessary.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/785263/518562

Comment: If you meant:  **the solution was simply running this command from tty1**:

`sudo rm .Xauthority`
what is tty1 here?

Comment: @Sohib - tty1 is terminal window 1, you can cycle through them with Ctrl Alt F1 (tty1),  F2 (tty2), F3 (tty3) ect.

Comment: @Android Dev - it did nothing unfortunately

Comment: @DavidThefan - It didn't help either..

Comment: I think I have tried everything on the Web. Does it mean  **there is no solution**? What should I do know?

Comment: The thing about Linux is, it is just as, if not *more* complicated in its structure than Windows. One broken dependency can wreck a dozen other programs. Honestly, I suggest that you just reinstall. It is possible to reinstall and retain all your files. See my answer on that here: http://askubuntu.com/a/841310/518562